# Subset de datos según la hora

Tags: r, r-dplyr

tengo una base de datos que tiene una columna que contiene la hora en la que se dio cierto evento, quiero hacer un subset con la franja de tiempo de 7 am a 9 am, teniendo en cuenta que la columna no contiene fecha, solo la hora.

```
 library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
 mi_df <- data.frame(      
  Variable1=c("oso","oso","tigre","tigre","tigre","oso","perro","gato","oso","oso",
             "tigre","tigre","tigre","oso","oso","tigre","tigre","tigre","oso",
             "oso","tigre","tigre","tigre","oso","oso","oso","tigre","tigre"),
 Variable2=c("08:56:20",NA,"07:25:15",NA,"08:56:45","08:18:13","10:38:26","03:52:38",
             "12:41:55","02:32:58","02:32:58",NA,"03:58:37","03:58:37","06:21:46",
              NA,"06:21:46","08:56:20",NA,"07:25:15","08:56:45","08:18:13",NA,
              "10:38:26","03:52:38",NA,"12:41:55",NA),
 Variable3=c("Manizales","Pereira",NA,"Bogota","Villavicencio","Pasto",NA,"Madrid",
             "Manizales","Pereira",NA,"Bogota","Pasto","Bogota","Villavicencio",
             NA,"Madrid","Pereira",NA,"Bogota","Villavicencio","Pasto","Bogota",
             "Pereira",NA,"Bogota","Villavicencio","Pasto"))

      mi_df$Variable2<-hms::as_hms(mi_df$Variable2)

    df<-mi_df%>%select(.........)(no sé como seguir)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como estás usando un objeto de la clase `hms` deberías hacer las comparaciones con otro objeto similar:

```
mi_df %>% 
  filter(Variable2 >= hms::hms(0, 0, 7), 
         Variable2 <= hms::hms(0, 0, 9))
```

Con `hms(ss, mm, hh)` construimos las horas que nos permitirán realizar el filtro